# Ember 3.12: Cancel subscription for event from service

Tags: ember.js

The following used to work:

```js
export default Route.extend({
  device: service(),

  activate() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    let device = get(this, 'device');
    device.one('change', this, this._onDeviceChange);
  },

  _onDeviceChange() {
    // ...
  },

  deactivate() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    let device = get(this, 'device');
    device.off('change', this, this._onDeviceChange);
    },
});
```

But "now" (in v3.12 here, most probably since a couple of versions) I get

> Error: Assertion Failed: You attempted to remove a function listener which did not exist on the instance, which means you may have attempted to remove it before it was added.

By removing the `device.off()`-part the error is gone, but I wonder: Is `off()` optional? Will removing `off()` produce some kind of leak? Why does the listener "not exist on the instance" anyway - given that `_onDeviceChange()` *is* triggered?

PS: I tried to `off` the listener before calling `_super`, but no difference...

---

Update: `device` extends [Evented](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Evented), which provides `one()` and `off()` see [API](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Evented):

```js
// app/services/device.js:
export default Service.extend(Evented, {

  // ...

  // eslint-disable-next-line ember/no-observers
  _deviceFlagChanged: observer('fooBar', function () {
    this.trigger('change');
  }),
});
```

Comment: I don't see `off` in the API for an Ember service at https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Service. Is it a special method on your `device` service that may be throwing the error?

Comment: Does `device` extend Ember.Evented?

Comment: @jrjohnson: It's from [Evented](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Evented), sorry, I'll add that in a minute. @stevenelberger: Yes – `one()` works, it's just the `off()` which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
export default Route.extend({
  device: service(),
  _onDeviceChangeHandler : null,
  init(){
      this._super(...arguments);
      _onDeviceChangeHandler = Ember.run.bind(this, this._onDeviceChange);  
  },
  activate() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    let device = get(this, 'device');
    device.one('change', this, this._onDeviceChangeHandler);
  },

  _onDeviceChange() {
    // ...
  },

  deactivate() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    let device = get(this, 'device');
    device.off('change', this, this._onDeviceChangeHandler);
    },
});
```

We need to remove the same reference we used for registering.

Comment: This is the strategy I used when registering event for window object. not sure this is required for your case.

Comment: Thanks, but no difference

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem but `_onDeviceChangeHandler = Ember.run.bind(this, this._onDeviceChange);` should probably be `this._onDeviceChangeHandler = Ember.run.bind(this, this._onDeviceChange);`

Comment: @jrjohnson: Yes, I thought so, too. I've tried that, plus variations of `set(this, '_onDeviceChangeHandler', ...)`, but without success. As far as I understand the error message, it seems to be a problem of `device` not "storing"/"remembering" the handler in the first place

Comment: @crusy Instead of `change` identifier you can try with some other name..